# Update file to text file on webpage

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, node.js

(If this is the wrong stack please let me know)

Consider the following: I have a nodejs file called `stbot.js`. This file I code on my laptop and transfer to my pi via github. However it kinda annoying to update the pi's code every time I update the code from my laptop, so I was wondering if there was some sort of command I could run to update that file's contents to what was on the github page (via the raw text or just the file itself)?

My pi runs the Raspberry Pi OS if that helps

Comment: wget or curl are two choices

Comment: @JaromandaX but how do I use them to do that

Comment: `wget URL-of-the-raw-file-on-github` similarly with `curl` - but I think I may have misunderstood ... you want to update the file on the pi without having to run anything on the pi?

Comment: Start with `man git` - it's all in there.

Comment: @JaromandaX I searched up `curl` documentation (I previously had no idea what it did) and that seems to be exactly what I am looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could youse Cron to pull the contents of your Github repository every minute.

1. Set up git with the terminal and connect it to your Github Repository.
2. You can edit the crontab like this: `crontab -e`.
3. Add this line: `*/1 * * * * git pull`.
4. Save and Exit.

Edit the file in your Repository and it should be updated on your Pi within a minute.

Cron docs: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md